# How do I remove a query string from URL using Python

Tags: python, http, cgi, urlparse

Example:

```
http://example.com/?a=text&q2=text2&q3=text3&q2=text4
```

After removing "**q2**", it will return:

```
http://example.com/?q=text&q3=text3
```

In this case, there were multiple "**q2**" and all have been removed.

Answer (score 86):

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse, urlunparse, parse_qs
else:
    from urllib import urlencode
    from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse, parse_qs

url = 'http://example.com/?a=text&q2=text2&q3=text3&q2=text4&b#q2=keep_fragment'
u = urlparse(url)
query = parse_qs(u.query, keep_blank_values=True)
query.pop('q2', None)
u = u._replace(query=urlencode(query, True))
print(urlunparse(u))
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/?a=text&q3=text3&b=#q2=keep_fragment
```

Comment: Best answer. One addition, [geturl](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.ParseResult.geturl) method of urlparse object can be used instead of urlunparse `print(u.geturl())`

Comment: If the goal is to remove all query params, wouldn't `u = u._replace(query='')` also work? We could avoid an extra import this way.

Comment: @kurifu The OP wanted to remove only one parameter, not the whole query.

Comment: Python 3 imports: `from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse, urlunparse, parse_qs`

Comment: access to a protected member _replace of a class.... how can we avoid this warning message?

Comment: @IamMashed This is how namedtuples work - https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace It's probably some kind of linter adding the warning.

Answer (score 86):

To remove all query string parameters:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse

url = 'http://example.com/?a=text&q2=text2&q3=text3&q2=text4'
urljoin(url, urlparse(url).path)  # 'http://example.com/'
```

For Python2, replace the import with:

```
from urlparse import urljoin, urlparse
```

Comment: I like this approach a _bit_ better than the popular answer because it doesn't call any internal APIs, but it will also eliminate URL fragments, whereas the popular answer will preserve them. It also doesn't solve the OP's exact question (it deletes _all_ query string parameters), but it solves mine :)

Comment: Was first looking into furl, but this removes the need to install another library. Works perferctly!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I came here twice after a few weeks since it is hard to remember and searched again for it.

Answer (score 27):

Isn't this just a matter of splitting a string on a character?

```
>>> url = http://example.com/?a=text&q2=text2&q3=text3&q2=text4
>>> url = url.split('?')[0]
'http://example.com/'
```

Comment: I was thinking about this solution as well. Can anyone tell me if there are any issue (potential bug/loophole) in this proposed solution?

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner There isn't one, really!

Comment: The problem will be clear if you carefully read the original question.  The OP wanted to remove only one parameter, all the query parameters.

Comment: This solution will work if all parameter was always sent  in the same order, if you work with a URL that have unordered parameters you end deleting the wrong parameter.

Answer (score 11):

Using python's url manipulation library **furl**:

```
import furl
f = furl.furl("http://example.com/?a=text&q2=text2&q3=text3&q2=text4")
f.remove(['q2'])
print(f.url)
```

Comment: Calling it 'python's url manipulation library' makes it sound like it's included in the standard lib, which it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

```
query_string = "https://example.com/api/api.php?user=chris&auth=true"
url = query_string[:query_string.find('?', 0)]
```

Comment: this does not exactly provide a solution for the given answer. please try improving your answer or deleting it.

Comment: While this code **may** answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply put, just use `url_query_cleaner()` from `w3lib.url`

```
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner

url = 'http://example.com/?a=text&q2=text2&q3=text3&q2=text4'
url_query_cleaner(url, ('q2'), remove=True)
```

Output: `http://example.com/?a=text&q3=text3`

Answer (score -2):

```
import re
q ="http://example.com/?a=text&q2=text2&q3=text3&q2=text4"
todelete="q2"
#Delete every query string matching the pattern
r = re.sub(r''+todelete+'=[a-zA-Z_0-9]*\&*',r'',q)
#Delete the possible trailing #
r = re.sub(r'&$',r'',r)

print r
```

Answer (score -2):

Or you could just  use strip

```
>>> l='http://example.com/?a=text&q2=text2&q3=text3&q2=text4'
>>> l.strip('&q2=text4')
'http://example.com/?a=text&q2=text2&q3=text3'
>>>
```